# Layer failed to load?

Tags: raster, pyqgis, ubuntu

I have this piece of codes running via pyqgis and trying to get **raster** layer from "**elevp.csv**". However, when executing this scripts it error kept returning "**Layer failed to load**". Anyone know how to solve this?

**test.py**

```
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

qgis_prefix="/usr"
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(qgis_prefix, True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

fileName="/home/ubuntu/pyqgis/elevp.csv?delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s&elevField=%s" % (";", "x", "y", "elev")
fileInfo=QFileInfo(fileName)
baseName=fileInfo.baseName()
rlayer=QgsRasterLayer(fileName, baseName)
if not rlayer.isValid():
  print "Layer failed to load"
```

**elevp.csv**

```
x;y;elev
1284120;6191000;419
136120;6181160;1558
1303800;6131960;436
933160;6105720;961
375560;6082760;518
382120;6063080;538
1421880;6059800;531
1067640;6036840;393
1175880;6020440;419
1218520;6020440;442
1838440;6017160;1532
```